# The differential equation $x'=ax^2+by^2$, $y'=cx^2+dy^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In a linear autonomous ODE $v'=Av$ we know almost everything there is to know about it. The next obvious generalization is to consider quadratic terms

$$\begin{bmatrix} x'\\ y'\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\end{bmatrix}+B\begin{bmatrix} x^2\\ y^2\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} c_1xy\\ c_2xy\end{bmatrix}$$

where for simplicity we work in dimension 2, since dimension 1 is just the Ricatti equation which is also solved. The terms $c_ixy$ can be of the order of $x$ or $y$ near the origin, which causes chaotic behavior as can be seen for example in the Lorenz system so assume they're $0$. The general equation seems to be equivalent to the case where $A=0$ up to a change of variables, which means we're left with

$$\begin{bmatrix} x'\\ y'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x^2\\ y^2\end{bmatrix}$$

for some constants $a,b,c,d$, which still seems to be plenty hard. I solved the case $a=1$ and $b=0$ for some values of $c,d$ which is equivalent to the Ricatti equation

$$y'=\frac c{1-t}+dy^2.$$

For some choices of parameters you get rational functions, and for some others rational functions of some weird power of $t$, and for some others nested logs and exponentials. Is there a closed form in general?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** This is intended as a comment and not a complete answer.
**Maple** provides this general solution:

$$\left[\left[\left\{x\! \left(t\right)=0\right\},\left\{y\! \left(t\right)=0\right\}\right],\left[\left\{x\! \left(t\right)=\mathit{RootOf}\! \left(-\left({{\int}}_{}^{\textit{_}Z}\frac{1}{\mathit{RootOf}\! \left(-2 \ln\! \left(\textit{_}a\right)-\left({{\int}}_{}^{\textit{_}Z}\frac{\textit{_}f \left(\textit{_}f^{2} b-\textit{_}f a b+\sqrt{\left(\textit{_}f-a\right) \left(\textit{_}f d-d a+b c\right)^{2} b}\right)}{\textit{_}f^{4} b-2 \textit{_}f^{3} a b-\textit{_}f^{3} d^{2}+\textit{_}f^{2} a^{2} b+3 \textit{_}f^{2} d^{2} a-2 d \,\textit{_}f^{2} b c-3 \textit{_}f \,d^{2} a^{2}+4 \textit{_}f d a b c-\textit{_}f \,b^{2} c^{2}+d^{2} a^{3}-2 a^{2} d b c+a \,b^{2} c^{2}}{d}\textit{_}f\right)+2 c_{1}\right) \textit{_}a^{2}}{d}\textit{_}a\right)+t+c_{2}\right)\right\},\left\{y\! \left(t\right)=\frac{2 a x\! \left(t\right) \left(\frac{d}{d t}x\! \left(t\right)\right)-\frac{d^{2}}{d t^{2}}x\! \left(t\right)}{2 a x\! \left(t\right)^{2} d-2 c x\! \left(t\right)^{2} b-2 \left(\frac{d}{d t}x\! \left(t\right)\right) d}\right\}\right]\right]$$

The first solution is the trivial solution $x(t)=0, y(t)=0$.
For the non-trivial solution we have to solve an algebraic equation for $x(t)$.
$y(t)$ then can be easily derived from $x(t)$.
But the **real** difficulty is the solution of the algebraic equation.